# Weak derivative of absolute value of function

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a domain. Suppose $u$ is locally integrable (i.e. $u\in L_{loc}^1(\Omega)$) and has a locally integrable weak derivative $\partial_i u$.

Is there a way to find the weak derivative of $\lvert u \rvert$?

I tried to show that $\partial_i \lvert u \rvert = \chi_{u>0}\partial_i u - \chi_{u<0}\partial_i u$. For this, I picked an arbitrary text function $\varphi$ and (using the dominated convergence theorem) showed that
$$
\int_{\Omega} \left(\chi_{u>0}\partial_i u - \chi_{u<0}\partial_i u\right)\phi
= \lim_{\epsilon \searrow 0} \int_{\Omega} \left[\left(\chi_{u>0} - \chi_{u<0}\right)\phi\right]_\epsilon\cdot \partial_i u
$$
where $\left[\left(\chi_{u>0} - \chi_{u<0}\right)\phi\right]_\epsilon$ denotes the mollified version of $\left(\chi_{u>0} - \chi_{u<0}\right)\phi$.

Then, since $\left[\left(\chi_{u>0} - \chi_{u<0}\right)\phi\right]_\epsilon$ is also a test function, there holds
$$
\int_{\Omega} \left[\left(\chi_{u>0} - \chi_{u<0}\right)\phi\right]_\epsilon\cdot \partial_i u
= -\int_{\Omega} \partial_i\left[\left(\chi_{u>0} - \chi_{u<0}\right)\phi\right]_\epsilon\cdot u
$$

Unfortunetly, this doesn't seem to be going anywhere? Any input is appreciated!

Comment: I remember seeing this problem solved somewhere on MathStackExchange. I will add a link if I find it, but you should try too, it's out there!

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz I tried looking for a similar question but unfortunately couldn't find it. Thank you!

Comment: Here it is. The only differences is that you're just considering one partial derivative at a time, and $L^1$ instead of $L^2$.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578760/if-u-in-h1-omega-then-u-in-h1-omega/2581254#2581254

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $u\in H^1(\Omega )$ then $|u|\in H^1(\Omega )$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578760/if-u-in-h1-omega-then-u-in-h1-omega)